# Save value by Button click on multiple activities

Tags: android

i have an app with 5 or so activities. In the end i want a formula to be filled up by values that come from Button Clicks and Input values.

Any idea how to do it?

Thx in advance

Comment: Store the values in one common place. You can use `SharedPreferences`, create your own subclass of `Application`, or create a singleton object, as mentioned by @user8090482

Answer (score 0):

You can go over [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) , but you can only save key-value pairs there. This solution is persistent and will save data on your device.

As far as I can see/read, you should make a static class named "DataHolder" or something like that, where you set and get the values from each activity. This solution is *not* persistent and will only save data during runtime.

Comment: I dont quite get what a key-value is. So i basically have e.g. one activity with 3 Editboxes to be input a value. Then when the button below is clicked, i want these values to be stored somewhere, so i can use them at the end of the app in the formula

Comment: A [HashMap](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/) is an example for key value pairs. Basically you map a value with a unique key. You get the value back by requesting with the key then. Edit: This sounds like you want to share data between activities. You should look up this in your favourite search engine, as it is a common problem and has *lots* of different approaches (like the mentioned application | singleton object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences for storing the value,below is sample code that will help you.
Make one common class to store values like below.

**Preferences.java**

```
public class Preferences{

     private Context context;

     public Preferences(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
     }

    // make getter setter like below as per your requirement

           public void setPhone(String phone) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("phone", phone);
            editor.apply();
        }

        public String getPhone(){
            SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            return preferences.getString("phone",null);
        }

        }
```

below is your MainActivity class.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

     private Preferences preferences;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            init();   
        }

     private void init(){

     preferences = new Preferences(MainActivity.this);

// for example you have three editbox then store each value like below,write below code in onClick(0 of your button

    preferences.setPhone(Edittext.getText().toString);

// and write below code wherever you want to get values 
   preferences.getPhone();
}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much but one problem. I dont really understand the first part. So how do i do it, that on buttonclick a specific value/variable is saved? Or maybe how a value of edittext gets saved.

Comment: I already mentioned that have a look.You can save value by  preferences.setPhone(Edittext.getText().toString) and get that value by preferences.getPhone() method.